# variable not initialized, BUT IT IS , right>

Tags: java, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Team based on this article : https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-declare-variables-javascript/

I declared and initialized my variable int result; 
Then assigned it a value within the block statements, ie

```
if(opCode == 'a') 
result = varX + varY
```

However, my print statement at end is receiving following error :

> Error:(32, 28) java: variable result might not have been initialized

thanks in advance.  This should help all the other newbies getting started on Conditional and block statements.  cODE is below.

```
package com.pluralsight.excercise1_conditionalstatements;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int varX = 10;
    int varY = 4;
    int result;
    char opCode = 'a';


    if (opCode == 'a') {
        result = varX + varY;
    } else if (opCode == 's') {
        result = varX - varY;
    } else if (opCode == 'd') {
        result = varX / varY;
    } else if (opCode == 'm') {
        result = varX * varY;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error, invalid code");
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is **Java** your link is for **JavaScript** - Completely different things.

Comment: It's complaining because your final `else` doesn't give it a value, so it's not initialized.

Comment: It is actually not right, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not initialized. It will only be initialized if one of your conditions is met. That's why the compiler is complaining.

You need to give it some int value when you declare it. For example:

```
int result = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is java compiling the potential of returning `result` that is not initialized.

Declaring the variable as `int result = 0;` should work.

Comment: Yup, changing it to int result = 0 worked, however changing it to int result = null, resulted in this error : Error:(7, 22) java: incompatible types: <nulltype> cannot be converted to int

Comment: @HansAlejandro That's good to know, I haven't been in Java for quite a while now. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

If opcode is not equal to a,s,d or m results never gets a value and than we you try to print it it gives an error. You have however set opCode to be equal to 'a' but java doesn't know that this means that result will get a value(of course we can see it does). So you should change int result to e.g.:

```
int result = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The computer is giving this information to you correctly because after the else statement, because you don't have a statement that exits the function cleanly. And you are using it uninitialized in the last println, right after the final else. So as a matter of fact, there is a pot by which the Lost print statement gets used, without result being initialized. If you put a return statement in the else block, the AST will figure out that the final print line where you're using the result is not reached, and stop giving you the warning.